# Icon size requirement error Xcode

Tags: xcode, icons, size

I am trying to validate an update for an app that I have in both iPhone and iPad versions. The validation is failing for both versions due to the following error:

> icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon
>   file must be 72x72 pixels, in .png format (-19014)

the iPhone version is giving a similar error with a 57x57 size.

The icon file is in png format and the required size for both versions.

I have tried deleting the icon file and re-inserting it in Xcode but this didn't seem to help. anyone run into similar problems?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try opening the icons with Preview and saving them over the originals. It may be a file format issue (saved from a third-party application).

Comment: Thanks Evan, I tried that as well didn't seem to help

Comment: Solved go to Build -> Packaging-> Compress PNG Files change to No and it should work

Comment: You should post this as an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: But this will increase the ipa file size. Any other solution? I hit this problem right now, the png files I product with PhotoShop CS5 for Mac.

Comment: No need to turn of png compression - you can just download an updated version of ApplicationLoader, install it, and then submit as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than turn off the useful compression of png files, you want to download the latest version of Application Loader.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg

This is described in the Apple Developer Forums.

You just need to install it and then you can submit from Xcode as normal.

Comment: This sounds like a good option if there are many png files will try this in my next update

Comment: It isn't an *option* it's the recommended solution from Apple Engineers. It's worth it for any amount of png files.

Answer (score 0):

Solved go to Build -> Packaging-> Compress PNG Files change to No and it should work

Answer (score 0):

use [this](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/)…

put in the image you want for a logo and it spits out the correctly sized icons...